# Blue tinted screen after login

Tags: server, login, lightdm

I freshly installed Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 and added ubuntu-desktop with lightdm to it. Everything is running fine, besides the fact that the screen is getting tinted blue after I log in. See attached images of before and after login. The colors during boot and on the login screen itself are fine, so the HDMI cable isn't the issue.

I can't find a solution for this. *Settings* -> *Color* doesn't show my display, so I can't make changes there.

[image]